# Remove unwanted multipolgon parts

Tags: postgis, polygon

I'm using the postcode boundary polygons from here: http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/

As the data is reconstructed, it has glitches here and there.

`SELECT geom FROM postcodes WHERE name = 'SW1A';` results in 01060000000300000001.

Mapped, this looks like [image: Postcode output]

The top two polygons are correct but the bottom blob is completely incorrect.

What would be the most efficient method to remove this?

Comment: You first have to describe how you know that the bottom blob is incorrect. What are your parameters to decide this?

Comment: Because this is a post code area and the proper postcode area does not include the blob :)

Comment: How can you be sure of that? What defines this blob as not being part of the postcode? (I'm being serious, you need to at least give information that defines a postcode in order to find geometries that are not)